# Superposition on a circuit with just one source

Tags: filter, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to analyse this circuit (state variable filter):

[image: svf]

All the places on the web I've found solve it first using superposition, creating an equation of the form \$ V_2 = kV_1 + kV_4 + kV_3 \$.

However, I can't understand how they use superposition in this circuit. There is only one source so how can it work? How can they get to that equation?

Comment: Label the nodes and show where the voltages are please. Nobody on this site is a mind reader.

Comment: @Andyaka done, that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superposition is actually used.

For a start assume V3 and V4 are zero then

V2 = -V1*R4/R1

Then assume V1 and V4 are zero then

V2 = \$\dfrac{V3\cdot R2}{R2+R3}\cdot (1+\dfrac{R4}{R1||R5})\$

Then assume V1 and V3 are zero and solve V2 in terms of V4

Finally, add all the different versions of V2 together as per superposition